# How to programmatically check a checkbox in gridview using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

How to programmatically check a checkbox in gridview using C#

Answer (score 4):

```
checkBox.Checked = True;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That answere my question.

Comment: no problem, I'm glad it was what you needed.  Also, welcome to StackOverflow and don't forget to accept the answers that answer your questions :)